# pandas groupby, split df and rename multiple sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(100)
cdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'customer': rng.choice(list('ACD'),size=(5)),
                   'segment': rng.choice(list('PQRS'),size=(5)),
                   'manager': rng.choice(list('QWER'),size=(5)),
                   'dumma': rng.choice((1234),size=(5)),
                   'damma': rng.choice((1234),size=(5))
})
```

I would like to do the below

a) create an excel file output with multiple sheets (based on segment column) for each manager (based on manager column)

b) For segment values - `Q,P and S`, check whether column `dumma` value is greater than column `damma` value

c) Instead of `out.xlsx`, save each file using the `{manager}.xlsx` name (from manager column)

d) If there are no records for any specific segment (len=0), then we need not create sheet for that segment

So, I tried the below

```
DPM_col = "manager"
SEG_col = "segment"

for i,j in dict.fromkeys(zip(cdf[DPM_col], cdf[SEG_col])).keys():
    print("i is ", i)
    print("j is ", j)
    data_output = cdf.query(f"{DPM_col} == @i & {SEG_col} == @j")
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    if len(data_output[data_output['segment'].isin(['Q','P','S'])])>0:
        if len(data_output[data_output['dumma'] >= data_output['damma']])>0:
            for seg, v in data_output.groupby(['segment']):
                v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"POS_decline_{seg}",index=False)
            writer.save()
    else:
        for seg, v in data_output.groupby(['segment']):
            v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"silent_inactive_{seg}",index=False)
        writer.save()
```

But it doesn't work. It only shows the value for `R` segment (which is in else clause)

I expect my output for each manager file to have multiple sheets like as below. If there are no records for any specific segment (len=0), then we need not create sheet for that segment

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need loop by all values in `DPM_col` column with write each manager to separate file with multiple sheets by conditions:

```
DPM_col = "manager"
SEG_col = "segment"

for manager, data_output in cdf.groupby(DPM_col):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{manager}.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    
        m1 = data_output['segment'].isin(['Q','P','S'])
        m2 = data_output['dumma'] >= data_output['damma']
        
        df = data_output[m1 & m2]
        for seg, v in df.groupby('segment'):
            v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"POS_decline_{seg}",index=False)

        df1 = data_output[~m1]
        for seg1, v1 in df1.groupby('segment'):
            v1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"silent_inactive_{seg1}",index=False)
```

EDIT: For avoid create empty files use:

```
DPM_col = "manager"
SEG_col = "segment"

for manager, data_output in cdf.groupby(DPM_col):
        m1 = data_output['segment'].isin(['Q','P','S'])
        m2 = data_output['dumma'] >= data_output['damma']
        mask = m1 & m2
        
        if mask.any() or not m1.any():
            with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{manager}.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    
                df = data_output[mask]
                for seg, v in df.groupby('segment'):
                    v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"POS_decline_{seg}",index=False)
    
                df1 = data_output[~m1]
                for seg1, v1 in df1.groupby('segment'):
                    v1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"silent_inactive_{seg1}",index=False)
```

Comment: one small issue. For `manager=E`, there is no records that meet the condition but still an empty excel file is created. we can just check len(df)>0 and then to_excel? or it will still create an empty excel file because you have `pd.ExcelWriter` at the top?

Comment: @TheGreat - Can you test new solution?